# How can I extract the sub-second part of the index from POSIXlt?

Tags: r

How can I extract the decimals from a POSIXlt object? as.numeric() only gives the seconds since the epoch.

```
as.character((as.POSIXlt(1366736969, origin="1970-01-01") + 0.001172))
[1] "2013-04-23 13:09:29.001172"
as.numeric((as.POSIXlt(1366736969, origin="1970-01-01") + 0.001172))
[1] 1366736969
```

Comment: No it doesn't, but that's all it prints: `as.numeric((as.POSIXlt(1366736969, origin="1970-01-01") + 0.001172)) %% 1`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as.numeric` does not only return the seconds, that's just how it's printed.  You can see this by increasing the precision.

```
options(digits.secs=6)
p <- as.POSIXct(1366736969, origin="1970-01-01") + 0.001172
as.numeric(p)
# [1] 1366758569
od <- options("digits")
options(digits=22)
as.numeric(p)
# [1] 1366758569.001172065735
```

If you want to extract the sub-seconds, just use `trunc`:

```
options(od)
p-trunc(p)
# Time difference of 0.001172066 secs
```

Comment: `p %% 1` also works for this.  (Edit - I see that you have this in your comment above!)